# Combining several logical conditions from a list

Tags: python, list, expression, exec, logical-operators

I'm trying to do something that is seemingly simple: I have a list whose elements are logical expressions and I want a function that combines them into one logical expression, using a chosen logical operator (& or | is enough).

The following code does this, however, shouldn't there be a better way of doing this? It doesn't feel very Python-esque to me (main problem I see is the use of "exec", does anyone have an idea how to do it without?):

```
def CombineLogicalExpressions(listofexpressions,operator,outputvariableName):
    ''' return a condition combined from individual ones
    listofexpressions = ["a == 1", "b == 2"]
    operator = "and"
    outputvariableName = 'myVar'
    '''
    #generate list from which the condition can be read:
    logicalconditions = []
    for expression in listofexpressions:
        logicalconditions.append(expression)
        logicalconditions.append(' ' + str(operator) + ' ')
    del logicalconditions[-1] # delete the final operator

    #create string that holds the full expression
    condition = ''
    for a in logicalconditions:
        condition = condition + a   
    condition = 'FinalExpression = (' + condition + ')'

    return condition

FinalExpression = False
a = 1
b = 2

condition = CombineLogicalExpressions(['a == 1', 'b == 2'] ,
                                           'and', 'FinalExpression')
#set FinalBooleanQueryResult to the outcome of executing condition:
exec condition
print FinalExpression
```

You are probably wondering why I would have the logical conditions as strings. This is a simplification in the code above. In reality, I have a container object 'someContainer' and it has a method '.contains(string)' which will return a query which can be used to slice the container and give all entries whose key contains 'string':

```
 #returns sliced someContainer with keys matching 'string'
 someContainer[someContainer.contains(string)]
```

Now I would like to extend the functionality of 'contain()' to be able to supply a list of strings:

```
#returns sliced someContainer with keys matching all strings in 'listofkeywords'
containsMultiple(someContainer, listofkeywords)
```

I hope this is not too long and specific to put people off! I have tried searching for answers, but to my surprise couldn't find anything.

Comment: I found in fact a way to do it without exec, using lambda ... but it is quite ugly:

map(lambda x,y: x & y, listofexpressions , reversed(listofexpressions))

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just loop over your list of conditionals in a function, returning `True` or `False` right away from that function? If `or`, you return `True` if any of them are `True`, and if `and`, you return `False` if any of them are `False`.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) builtin functions.

Comment: Yes, you're right ... but have a look at the comments I make at the end. In fact, I have a list of queries which slice a container and I want to combine them ... without having to completely re-write the container class.

Comment: I just realized I still didn't quite get what the API of your `Container` looks like, so my answer may not apply. But it's nearly impossible to give an answer to that without knowing more about that API - are the queries strings or some sort of query objects? Do sliced containers support addition? What framework are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I found a very nice and neat solution for my problem, using the "reduce" function and the operator module. The operator module turns a binary operator into a function that takes two arguments, like:

```
 operator.and_(A,B) equivalent to: (A and B).
```

Reduce will apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to a list of arguments, i.e.

```
reduce(function,[A,B,C]) equivalent to: function( A, function(B,C) )
```

With this I'll give the code which is solving the original simplified problem I gave below. Note that this, in particular, also works perfectly for the containers I am actually interested in:

```
def CombineLogicalExpressionsBetter(listofexpressions,operatorname):
    '''
    use as:
    CombineLogicalExpressionsBetter([a == 1, b == 2, c == 'z'], 'and')
    '''
    import operator

    #make it easier for users to enter operators:
    if operatorname in ('and','and_') :
        operatorname = operator.and_
    elif operatorname in ('or','or_'):
        operatorname = operator.or_
    elif operatorname in ('not','not_'):
        operatorname = operator.not_
    else:
        raise Exception("Please enter a valid operator: 
                    'and', 'or', 'not' ... I got: " + operatorname)


    #combine expression:
    totalexpression = reduce(operatorname, (expression for expression in
                                                       listofexpressions))

    return totalexpression
```

Answer (score 2):

You could easily use the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) or [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) builtins for this:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    def contains(self, s):
        return s in self.items


def contains_any(some_container, items):
    return any((some_container.contains(i) for i in items))


def contains_all(some_container, items):
    return all((some_container.contains(i) for i in items))


c = Container(['foo', 'bar'])

print contains_any(c, ['foo', 'qux'])
print contains_all(c, ['foo', 'qux'])
print contains_all(c, ['foo', 'bar'])
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```

---

The `(some_container.contains(i) for i in items)` inside the `any()` or `all()` calls is a so called [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). It's similar to a list comprehension, but it's lazy, possibly saving you plenty of calls to `Container.contains()`.

Comment: Also, you don't need parentheses around generator expression if it's a sole function argument.

Comment: Thanks for this @Lukas, but as you noted yourself it doesn't quite solve my problem. To pick up your questions: the problem is that I know little about the containers myself. I'm working for a big company and this stuff is managed by a core team, so it very difficult to change any of it. On the other side, my solution with exec() is unsafe and is unlikely to ever make it into production. So my question here is whether there is an easy way out...I understand that the "right" thing to do is to build this into the container class directly, but the real world is sometimes not that easy.